# Average Offset Index Match formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to average the most recent 6 values of 'x' - however, I'm getting reference errors when trying to average them. The value I'm looking for should be 8,720.33 with the criteria of 'x'. The dates have no bearing in the formula, just a visual reference point.

Formula I'm getting lost on "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDEX(C2:C42,MATCH(E2,B2:B42,0),),0,0,-6))"

*Note - the dates are being updated daily to include historical data points

Data Set:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `the most recent 6 values`? How you will detect which are most recent as your data increase. So, date is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C1:C25,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A1:A25)/(B1:B25=E2),ROW(A1:A6)),0))))
```

or with full ranges:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C:C,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A:A)/(B:B=E2),ROW(A1:A6)),0))))
```

Confirm it with `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: The dates are dynamic and constantly updating (I'm bringing in a query via SQL) is there a way to make the ROW statement dynamic to include an ever growing range of data? That function in particular is why I was thinking the offset -6

Comment: @Bbow987 You can use full column ranges, See edit.

Comment: @basic fyi, when using Office 365 youd don't need to enter Array-Formulas with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`. Normal `Enter` is of now enough

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to pull this off with `AVERAGEIFS` if you add a rank column that ranks Header1 by date.

In my example:

Column D is the Values you are averaging
Column B is Hearder1
Column C is the rank - `=COUNTIFS($B:$B,B2,$A:$A,">"&A2)+1`

`=AVERAGEIFS($D:$D, $B:$B, "x", $C:$C, "<7")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, not sure if it's exactly what I'm looking for though... as the value of the last 6 averaged values (most recent, i.e. date) should be 8,720 =AVERAGE(c4:c9)

Comment: try now, my rank was backwards

Comment: Also I have included the rank formula

Comment: With this formula you can easily read it and change the rank filter much more easily than the other answer. Say you want the most recent 7, then you just change the arg to <8

Comment: @Bbow987 Also, your data does not need to be sorted. The formulas will work even if you dates or Header1 are mixed up